# How do I get rhythmbox to play MPEG1 files?

Tags: rhythmbox

I am new user and i installed Ubuntu 12.04 with dual booting. As I played a song its not working asking a MPEG1  to install for the song. Is there any alternative to play the song without installation. I searched the sites and i found to install

```
sudo apt-get install Ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

I have connected INTERNET from android mobile through tethering. I can access internet but it is very slow in downloading. I am trying from software center but its taking lot of time to install. Please help me to download the package via terminal and to download faster.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to play an MPEG file, You can play it with installing `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` which is much smaller in size as compared to `ubuntu-restricted-extras` (with all it's dependencies, which is 67.0 MB in total size).
So you might want to install it without using the big metapackage (ubuntu-restricted-extras includes all codecs and flash).

Install it by clicking on the button:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or open a terminal and use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

It is about 8,342 kB in size

Comment: A.S. is right. My only caveat to add to that is you may be better off finding a way to install the restricted extras package simply because you will find similar issues later when you try to play other media formats. Better to solve it all at once I say!

Comment: @LinuxPCplus thanks. I was dealing with the specific case. Your comment was helpful

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there is no way to play these without the restricted extras. This is because Ubuntu cannot install these proprietary drivers by default. From my own experience, I know tethering is often way to slow for such tasks. If you do not have a home network, I suggest finding a pyblic wifi. Most libraries & hospitals have one. As do many fast food restaraunts.

Comment: Thank you,I will find alternative to speed up the INTERNET.As you said i will find wifi or i will find to connect 3g net from this.